Prerender.io Docker image and strange url access
I use the Prerender.io Docker image from https://github.com/tvanro/prerender-alpine?tab=readme-ov-file, and in the Docker logs, I see tons of the following URL access:
2024-06-26T15:59:32.559Z getting https://polykill.io/q6dfofw74d8
2024-06-26T15:59:32.559Z getting https://polykill.io/q6dfofw74d8
2024-06-26T15:59:32.559Z getting https://polykill.io/q6dfofw74d8
2024-06-26T15:59:32.559Z getting https://polykill.io/q6dfofw74d8
2024-06-26T15:59:32.561Z getting https://polykill.io/h3czqdzcu2
2024-06-26T15:59:32.568Z getting https://polykill.io/h3czqdzcu2
2024-06-26T15:59:32.569Z getting https://polykill.io/h3czqdzcu2
2024-06-26T15:59:32.570Z getting https://polykill.io/hn7ffde8hx9
2024-06-26T15:59:32.570Z getting https://polykill.io/hn7ffde8hx9
2024-06-26T15:59:32.570Z getting https://polykill.io/hn7ffde8hx9
2024-06-26T15:59:32.570Z getting https://polykill.io/hn7ffde8hx9
2024-06-26T15:59:32.570Z getting https://polykill.io/1igwbqt4ubi
2024-06-26T15:59:32.570Z getting https://polykill.io/qi4hbbew1dj

and then failure with the following error:
[8:0x7f2866a5c3f0]  7174949 ms: Mark-sweep 4054.5 (4140.2) -> 4049.1 (4132.7) MB, 831.8 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.577, current mu = 0.066) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[8:0x7f2866a5c3f0]  7176353 ms: Mark-sweep 4059.5 (4135.1) -> 4055.7 (4155.1) MB, 1387.4 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.310, current mu = 0.012) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed

What could be the reason for that?

polykill.io is a site created to protect against a chinese base malware attack enabled by their acquisition of polyfill.io. As to the errors and the software you are using, I have no experience: : https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/polyfillio-javascript-supply-chain-attack-impacts-over-100k-sites/
